# Change MAC address of Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260

Tags: windows, windows-8, network-adapter, mac-address

I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/519189/how-to-change-the-mac-address-in-win-8-to-spoof-a-roku-player-through-a-wifi-spl), but my card doesn't seem to have that option. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: did you tried to create a virtual machine with a virtual network interface directly connected to your local network without a bridge ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I change the MAC address of my Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 adapter?

This is not possible. For security reasons, Intel does not support this practice.

> The Media Access Control (MAC) address is hard-coded on Intel wireless
>   adapters and cannot be changed.
>
> Some third-party software applications can "spoof" a MAC address to a
>   different address, but for security reasons, Intel does not support
>   this practice.
>
> Beginning with 12.x wireless driver package, the possibility of
>   "spoofing" the MAC address was blocked to prevent this practice.

The article includes a list of products this applies to (the list includes the
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260).

Source 
[Can I Change the MAC Address for My Wireless Adapter?](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000006057.html)

Comment: I tested it on latest linux kernel, this is something entirely possible even if the Intel’s driver is written as binary blob.

Comment: This is easy as pie in Ubuntu so it has nothing to do with the hardware.

Comment: @Jake The question is tagged Windows.

Answer (score 17):

Although Intel doesn't support it anymore, it still does work for me with the AC 7260 and driver version 17.15.0.5.

Only thing that took me some tries and searching was the fact that Microsoft restricts spoofing for wireless cards in Windows, so that you have to use 2,6,A or E for the second character.

So your MAC has to follow one of these patterns:

```
X2-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

X6-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

XA-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

XE-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
```

If you add the following to your registry you should even be able to edit it again in the advanced configuration options. **BUT BEWARE** to find the correct ID number for **your** wireless adapter. So please change the key name "0002" in the following code to the correct number for your card. To find that go to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` in the registry and look through the keys named "0000", "0001" etc. and look for their "DriverDesc" values when making a *.reg file and before adding it to your registry.

Code for registry file is the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002\Ndi\Params\NetworkAddress]

"ParamDesc"="Network Address"

"default"="000000000000"

"LimitText"="12"

"Optional"="1"

"type"="edit"

"UpperCase"="1"
```

Copy the text above to a blank text document, edit the number in the registry path, save it as a .reg file and then run it to apply.

Comment: Nice tip, but why is the second hex number limited to that 4 one?

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. Anybody had success with this recently?

Comment: @f1LL : one which Windows® version ?

Comment: @Demiurg no luck either. My guess is they removed the parameter.

Comment: Worked for me on a i7-5500U with Wireless-AC 7265 adapter with the 19.1.0.4 driver!!! I'm curious about why the limitation of the second character.

Comment: @rekire Because otherwise the MAC address would either be a broadcast address, a universally administered address, or both.

Comment: workds, and fun.

Comment: I confirm that this works for Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, driver version 19.50.1.5 (on Windows 10).  Using E as the second char freaks out some portal access points, but 2 works okay.

Comment: Thanks. Works on Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 (same with @William), driver Version 19.50.1.6

Comment: @RonaldRamos it doesn’t works for me. Which is the the Windows® version ?

Comment: So Windows enforces the octet rule even when changing it using the drivers?

Comment: Worked with Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 using driver 20.70.25.2 on Windows 11. However, when this address is set, Windows' *Random hardware addresses* functionality stops working (option greyed out in Settings)

Comment: Doesn't work for me: windows 19043 driver: 22.30.0.11.
It adds the network line in the settings, but after setting it, the mac address doesn't change @ ipconfig /all